# How to implement DateTime

Tags: c#

Can anyone please show me how do I implement `DateTime` on this code? Tried to google around but still confusing on this code.

```
     public double CalcLastCouponDate(DateTime dtmBaseDate, DateTime dtmLastDate, int intCouponTermMonths, int intFixedCouponDay, string strOddLastCouponType)
    {
        int i = 0;
        DateTime dtmLastCoupon;
        {
            if (strOddLastCouponType == "S")
            {
                return dtmLastCoupon = DateAdd("M", -intCouponTermMonths, dtmLastCoupon); // How to convert DateAdd to C#
            }
            else
            {
                return dtmLastCoupon = DateAdd("M", -2 * intCouponTermMonths, dtmLastCoupon); // How to convert DateAdd to C#
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsEndDayofMonth(DateTime DateIn)
    {
        int intLastDay = 0; 
        bool IsEndDay = false;

        intLastDay = CalcEndDayofMonth(Year(DateIn), Month(DateIn)); // Convert Year, Month to C#
        if (intLastDay == Day(DateIn)) // Convert Day to C#
        {
        IsEndDay = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsEndDay = false;
        }
        return IsEndDay;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It's unclear from the code.

Comment: I just wan to replace that DateAdd to DateTime, as u know DateAdd cannot convert into C#.. I struggle few days to solve this code.. Hope u can help..

Comment: What is `DateAdd`? Never seen it in the .NET CLR. What are `intCouponTermMonths`, `dtmLastCoupon`? As to creating an instance of DateTime: `new DateTime(2014, 12, 31);`

Comment: Can post a code here? DateAdd("M", -intCouponTermMonths, dtmLastCoupon); stuck in this area.. DateAdd does not exist in current context.. Also Day, Month and Year.. Mind to help solve this problem?

Comment: Did you guys actually *read* his code before voting to put it on hold? Just wondering.

Comment: Thanks James for helping.. The code is done.. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming DateAdd has normal semantics it would probably look something like this:

```
public DateTime CalcLastCouponDate(DateTime dtmBaseDate, DateTime dtmLastDate, int intCouponTermMonths, int intFixedCouponDay, string strOddLastCouponType)
{
    return (strOddLastCouponType == "S") ?
        dtmLastDate.AddMonths(-intCouponTermMonths) :
        dtmLastDate.AddMonths(-2 * intCouponTermMonths);
}

public bool IsLastDayOfMonth(DateTime dateIn)
{
    return dateIn.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateIn.Year, dateIn.Month);
}
```

Etc.

Comment: Sir I post the actual code.. Mind to review and show me how to change it? Thank you for helping sir..

Comment: You're welcome/good luck ;)

Comment: Still error on  return dtmLastCoupon.AddMonths(-intCouponTermMonths); sir.. Mind to help?

Comment: CalcLastCouponDate should return a DateTime IMO.

Comment: Depending on whether you're calculating forward from the base date or backward from the end date, you'd either switch `dtmLastDate` to `dtmBaseDate` or change the polarity of `-intCouponTermMonths` and `-2 * intCouponTermMonths`.

Comment: It's 100% fixed.. Thank you again sir.. I wish I can donate u.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

can u give a clear idea what you are trying to achieve.

have a look on the below links I think you may find your need.

[Custom date time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[DateTime methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx)